# multiple select drop down not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to add multiple select drop down in `asp.net` but its not working. It shows error in multiple field.

**How can I fix this issue?**

I am using `bootstrap multi select plugin`

[image]

```
<select  id="Select1" multiple="multiple" runat="server">    
    <option value="Text for Item 1" selected="selected"> Item 1 </option>
    <option value="Text for Item 2"> Item 2 </option>
    <option value="Text for Item 3"> Item 3 </option>
    <option value="Text for Item 4"> Item 4 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: kindly include all relevant code to the question or better yet create a snippet to replicate the problem

Answer (score 0):

For create a select multiple, you just need add ***multiple*** in your tag.

```
<select  id="Select1" runat="server" multiple>
```

Take a look at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp)

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/   this plugin iam using

Comment: Asp underline your multiple="multiple" cause the proper use is just multiple. After that there is no problem for launch your app. You just have to use correctly the plugin